# Some questions by nature attract down votes

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

When I was very new to SO I asked some very stupid questions. The reason for this is the steep learning curve for someone new to writing code. I never took those down votes as offensive. Some people noticed I was just new to all this and give very good advice.

The only reason I now still come to ask something on SO is to find out about issues that are either undocumented or require a lot of time/work to figure out.

These questions might appear stupid, like this one: [red color of delete button in UITableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142488/what-is-the-red-color-of-a-tableview-delete-button)
People either thought I was asking:
what is the color of UIColor.redColor()? (which is a retarded or troll question)
or they never realised there was a difference in color between redColor and the red color of the delete button.

Only someone who actually read the question knows I did not mean redColor when I typed red color and that I was talking about the shade of red of the delete button.

Some weeks later I had another very specific question about something that required a lot of time to figure out and probably some money too. Nothing like it asked on SO yet so time to write a new question.

This time I thought I would tell quick down voters that I knew a hack but was looking for a solution. Trying to avoid down votes on account for apparent stupidity.

Obviously it now attracts troll down votes...

So is there any way to add a "I know what I am doing/asking" tag to a question. A way to tell people: I did my research, this isn't a duplicate,... Without saying "don't down vote please"

Comment: If there were such a tag how would you control whether you could use it or not? Put your research in the question if you've done some.

Comment: No, such a tag would be a meta tag, and we don't do those.

Comment: Keep improving / refining your question.  If you ever find yourself adding a comment to your own question to explain to other users what you meant in more detail, STOP.  Instead, edit your question to add the relevant details and then add a comment indicating that you have updated the question to add more detail.

Comment: Realised that 5 minutes ago thanks to the answer of Hans...
Going over my questions at the moment and updating them.
A lot of people might only read the question and deem it unworthy, even though the comments might explain more...

Comment: Your recent edit represents a significant improvement to the question.  I might nit pick at some of your grammar, but the really important information is all there now.

Comment: English is not my first language so my grammar is awful. Code is so much easier than a real language :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are no such tags and they shouldn't be created either. They are [meta tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/meta-tags/info) that don't tell us much about the content of the question you're going to ask.

If you know what you're doing, your question should reflect that in its clarity. If you don't want to get downvoted, your question should be clear enough to prevent that from happening.

The title of your question however is

> what is the red color of a tableview delete button?

That's not a great title. The "obvious" answer would be "Well, red". You then ask

> Hi anyone knows what the color of the delete button in a tableview is?

Well, you just told us. It's red.

If instead you would have asked "What are the RGB values for the color of the Tableview delete button?", your question would have been more clear. You could then refer to the "red-ish color" in your question and nobody would be confused.  (Though it probably would still be a poor question and might not be well-received).

So overall, we don't need such tags, and you could have been more clear.

Comment: I could have been a bit more clear. But this doesn't take away that most people were convinced that UIColor.redcolor was the correct answer. Most people didn't notice the slight difference in color. My assumption when I asked the question was that people did know that redcolor() was not the color of the delete button and someone would just simply answer the correct RGBA values. But I did not know that  these sort of things are meta tags. And if allowed more would follow and it would be awful, I agree

Comment: I disagree about it being a poor question. It is something that is undocumented by Apple and not a duplicate question.

Comment: If you did notice the slight difference and knew it wasn't redColor, make sure to include such information in your question. The more precise you can be, the less of an opportunity you'll leave for misinterpretation.

Answer (score 18):

> Hi anyone knows ...

This is one way you can tell that you are asking a poor question.  I classify these kind of questions as *helpdesk questions*.  You are only interested in a little factoid, a simple fact to help you get unblocked.

But you haven't actually learned anything.  The next time you need to know the color of another UI gadget you are going to have to ask the exact same question again.  Oh dear, are we really going to fill SO with the colors of *every* single UI gadget?  Also note that you got a helpdesk answer.  It just told you the factoid, you don't even know if the answer is accurate without trying it.  He didn't spend any time explaining how he *discovered* this factoid.  Anybody that's going to google your question some day is likely to have a "crap, not *that* button" moment.

This is just plain bad Q+A.

You could just as easily have asked the *real* question, "How do I discover the colors of iOS gadgets?"  Now somebody is going to give you the fish and you, as well as everybody else that reads the question, will know how to solve it forever.  Probably something having to do with creating a screenshot and using the color dropper in a painting program.  Whatever it takes in [ios].

Don't ask helpdesk questions.  Ask for the fish.

Comment: absolutely true. The reason I didn't ask for the method to get the color is because it is a rare thing to have a UI element that you didn't set yourself, have (up until iOS8) no control over and is not visible in xcode. So I asked for a specific answer (helpdesk question) and I got a lot of down votes, one guy teaching me how to fish in a bucket for steak and one guy who gave a clear and correct answer. That doesn't take away the fact that down votes are the least effective way to improve a question like that. Especially since it comes down to phrasing.